# Fancytree: How send one event complete multi selection at one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I using Fancytree for my project.

#### The following source matrix

https://jsfiddle.net/middle536/spwsvsoz/

```
source: [
        {title: "Folder 1", folder: true, keyid: "id1"},
        {title: "Folder 2", folder: true, keyid: "id1,id2"},
        {title: "Folder 3", folder: true, keyid: "id1,id3", children: [
            {title: "Node 3.1"},
            {title: "Node 3.2"}
        ]},
        {title: "Folder 4", folder: true, keyid: "id3"}
    ],
```

I have an array. see above source matrix.
Every folder have multi keyid.
This example select all keyid = id2 useing #button1.
The selection have two folder selected.
Fancytree will send selection 2 times (see alert).

If selected 3 folder or node. Fancytree will send those selection 3 times.

This will cause my code to malfunction.

#### The following is my code

```
$(function(){
$("#tree").fancytree({
    checkbox: true,
    ...
    source: {source },

    extensions: ["edit", "table", "gridnav","childcounter","filter"],

    select: function(event, data) {

            //Here have a jquery datatable update function.
            //When #button1 click function do multi selection
            //the jquery datatable will alert error message.

    },

    table:....
})

$("#button1").click(function(){
    var key_ids = new Array();
    var nodeList = new Array();
        $("#tree").fancytree("getTree").visit(function(node){
            if(typeof node.data.keyid != "undefined"){
                key_ids = node.data.keyid.split(",");
                for (var i = 0; i < key_ids.length; i++) {
                    if(key_ids[i] == 'id2'){
                        //node.setSelected(true);//this do multi select multi times
                        //alert(key_ids);
                        nodeList.push(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        nodeList.setSelected(true);//this do multi select one time, but can't work.
});
```

#### The question is ...

I know nodeList.setSelected(true); is wrong syntax.
The idea is multi node select one time.
Not multi node select multi times.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From [your comment here](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/831#issuecomment-361020226), I assume that you want only one alert in that case.
This is not related to Fancytree, since *you* are sending the 'event' (marked by the 'alert()' call.

However, you could change your code to collect all matches before, and send at once:

```
var i, key_ids,
    nodeList = [];

$("#tree").fancytree("getTree").visit(function(node){
  if( node.data.keyid ){
    key_ids = node.data.keyid.split(",");
    for (i = 0; i < key_ids.length; i++) {
      if(key_ids[i] === 'id2'){
        node.setSelected(true);
        nodeList.push(node);
      }
    }
  }
});
alert($.map(nodeList, function(o){ return o.title; }).join(", "));
```

Comment: Sorry, forget "alert", "node.setSelected(true)" is the point I want. My idea is nodeList.setSelected(true). In addition, I update the post. For this question does you have other suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that calling setSelected() multiple times is a problem?

Comment: If select the checkbox one by one, the jquery datatable work fine. But using above for{ node.setSelected(true);}, will lead to datatable error. Is there a way to write node.setSelected(true) like node.setSelected(node1,node2,node3....)?

Comment: The select event needs to be generated once per node, even if there was a ‚selectMulti()‘ method. It seems rather to be a problem with datatable if this causes faults (you could try to implement some kind of buffering though)